# Installing nix: where is shell profile - MacOS using zsh?

Tags: nix, macos

I am trying to install nix on my local iMac. I am following the following [Guide](https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/MacOS.html) to do that.  After executing

```
sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume
```

I get "Installing finished!" and I am requested to add the line:

```
. /Users/joeblogs/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh
```

"to your shell profile (e.g. ~/.profile)."

I am using a Mac (with zsh) and so what file is this shell profile referring to? For instance, i do not have a ~/.profile.

Comment: You'd have an easier time installing on a Linux machine. Try Linux mint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following worked. Go to the following file:

```
/etc/zprofile
```

and add the following line:

```
. /Users/thanhdanhphan/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh
```

Close all your terminals and re-open a new one, try:

```
nix --version
```

and it should give you the latest nix version e.g (at the time of writing):

```
nix (Nix) 2.3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Try creating a file named .bash_profile in your user directory (/Users/joblogs/.bash_profile) and add the given line as it is written.  Restart the terminal and give it a go.

Comment: this does't work, maybe because i am using zsh